# Same query in RDS taking different latency at different instances

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

We have deployed our Fast API in EKS and connected with RDS Postgres. It is a simple select query with few where clauses. The RDS is in test environment. (Hence there is no load and all the metrics seem to be normal)
Latency during five different hits are 20ms, 40ms, 150ms, 25ms, 30ms.

What could be the probable reason?

Tried monitoring all the metrics.
Also tried time profiling in different parts of API code.